# Kendo Export to Excel is not working in IE

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am tryng to export current grid data to excel it is working good in chrome but its not working for IE.How i can acheive this task and make it work in IE ? Any suggetion or help will be appreciated.

gridConfig.JS

```
toolbar: [
        {
            template: kendo.template('<a  href="" class=\'k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-add\' ng-click=\'addNewRole();\'><span class=\'k-icon k-add\'></span>Add Entity</a>')
        },
        "excel"
    ],    excel: {
        fileName: "Subcategory Export.xlsx",
       // proxyURL: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/export",
        filterable: true
    },
```

Comment: For older versions of IE (8,9) you need to implement a server proxy: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/save-files/introduction#server-proxy-%20implementations

Comment: If i understand this correct ,Do we need to write code at backend side...?

Comment: Yes - if you scroll down a little on the link it's maybe 10 - 15 lines of code.  If you have a grid with a lot of data, it might be worth noting that when I had to implement this I saw javascript errors about long running scripts which you can just "OK" your way through.

Comment: so once we get response from server using URl that is being created ..how i will implement into front end side. Do i just need to call Api or i have to write some extra code to get the data in excel sheet.

Comment: got it working its more like backend work we created one end point where we can post the grid data with base-64 and backend is sending an attachment..

Answer (score 1):

got it working its more like backend work we created one end point where we can post the grid data with base-64 and backend is sending an attachment